Operator's definition in Dirac picture
I have a question about the definition of quantum operators in the Dirac picture. The definition is: $$A=\sum_i \sum_j \vert i \rangle A_{ij} \langle j \vert.\tag{1}$$
By deplacing the ket vector I get:$$A=\sum_i \sum_j  A_{ij} \langle j \vert i \rangle.\tag{2}$$
At this point  $ \langle j \vert i \rangle$ is the inner product which, assuming that we are dealing with an orthonormal basis, gives $0$ whenever $j \neq i$. If so the matrix representing the operator $A$ is always diagonal, but we know that this statement is wrong. What am I missing?

How did you get from the 1st equation to the second equation? The Second equation will be a number, not an operator. You can't just move the ket to the right. The top equation is an outer product but the bottom is an inner product.

$\langle j \vert i \rangle$ is not equal to $\vert i \rangle \langle j \vert$.

How did you get from the 1st equation to the second equation? The Second equation will be a number, not an operator. You can't just move the ket to the right. The top equation is an outer product but the bottom is an inner product. The issue is moving the ket past the bra.
For example in two dimensions, let $ |a\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $ \langle b| = \begin{bmatrix} 0 1 \end{bmatrix}$
Then $\langle b| a \rangle = 1$, but $ |a \rangle\langle b| =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ these are different mathematical operations.


I have a question about the definition of quantum operators in the Dirac picture. The definition is: $$A=\sum_i \sum_j \vert i \rangle A_{ij} \langle j \vert.\tag{1}$$
By deplacing the ket vector I get:$$A=\sum_i \sum_j  A_{ij} \langle j \vert i \rangle.\tag{2}$$
At this point  $ \langle j \vert i \rangle$ is the inner product which, assuming that we are dealing with an orthonormal basis, gives $0$ whenever $j \neq i$. If so the matrix representing the operator $A$ is always diagonal, but we know that this statement is wrong.


What am I missing?

The outer product is generally not equal to the inner product.
For example, if $|a\rangle$ has a matrix representation as
$$
|a\rangle \to \left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and if $|b\rangle$ has a matrix representation as
$$
|b\rangle \to \left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)
$$
then
$$
|a\rangle\langle b| \to \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)\tag{1}
$$
whereas
$$
\langle b|a\rangle \to 0\;.\tag{2}
$$
Obviously, the right-hand sides of replacement (1) and replacement (2) are not equal. Since the matrix representations are not equal, the abstract notations are not equal.

Notationally, you must have already agreed that the notation $|a\rangle\langle b|$ means the outer product of $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$. You must have already agreed that the notation $\langle c| d\rangle$ means the inner product of $|c\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$.
Therefore, you simply cannot replace the outer product of two kets
$$
|i\rangle\langle j|\tag{3}
$$
with the inner product of two kets
$$
\langle j | i \rangle\;.\tag{4}
$$
There is no reasonable sense in which you can "move" the $\langle j|$ in expression (3) to the "left" of the $|i\rangle$ in espression (3) to obtain expression (4). Doing so is simply notational nonsense.
